# How to select date from date picker in Katalon Studio?

Tags: automation, webui, katalon

How to select date from the calendar. Calendar is designed using html component only.

**Date component**
[image]

Is there any way we can do this?

I'm able to open calendar with WebUI.clickOffset() but unable to select any date.
WebUI.SetText() is also not working.